# ExtJS 4.2 Collapsible Panel Expand strange visual behavior

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I'm getting a strange behavior with a `Panel` that is collapsible.

My app is running on 4.2.1, but I have create a `JSFiddle` to simulate the issue:

**UPDATE**
I create Sencha Fiddle (better) https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7vk

I have a main panel that holds two items: a Grid with `flex: 1` and a Panel in the bottom that is `collapsible`.

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
        title:'Grid',
        flex: 1,
        columns:[]
    });

    var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        title:'Hola',
         layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'grid',
                padding: 10,
                title: 'test',
                columns:[],
                flex: 1,
                border: 1
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                padding: 10,
                title: 'test',
                collapsible: true,
            collapsed: true,
            height: 300,

                border: 1
            }
        ]
});
```

> When you expand the panel it the **animation** goes to the top of the view and then goes down. Very strange.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in ExtJS 5. If you don't really need that animation, you can just turn it off on that Panel: `animCollapse: false`

The Panel should now collapse correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the containing element's layout event only occurs once the child has stopped collapsing/expanding. The issue is that the main container is too small for the panel to expand. As its fixed position and size is changed during the animation, it becomes awkward like you saw.

My best solution would be to have a bigger container so that the restriction does not appear. There are many ways to do this. Here's your code contained in a viewport:

```
Ext.require(['*']);

Ext.onReady(function() {    
    Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
        title: 'Hola',
        layout: {
            type: 'border',
            padding: 5
        },
        defaults: {
            split: true
        },
        items:[
            Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
                title:'Hola',
                region: 'center',
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'grid',
                    title: 'test',
                    columns:[],
                    flex: 1,
                    border: 1
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'test',
                    collapsible: true,
                    collapsed: true,
                    height: 300,
                    border: 1
                }
            ]
        })        
        ]
    });
});
```

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/mYp4r/

Comment: I see the same animation strange behavior.. The panel header goes to the top of the other panel for a second.